# Extract html as a literal string

Tags: jquery, html

If I have a label and its contents are set up like so

```
<label>
    "Thi"
    <b>
        s i
    </b>
    <b style="font-style: italic;">s a</b>
    <u>
        <b style="font-style: italic;">&nbsp;test </b>
        <i>for </i>
        extracting&nbsp;
    </u>
    stuff
</label>
```

Which would read, "Thi**s i*s a test*** for extracting stuff" where some overlapping underlining would be applied as well from "a" to "extracting".

How would I go about extracting the contents of the label into a string that would read like so:

`"Thi"<b>s i</b><b style="font-style: italic;">s a</b><u><b style="font-style: italic;">&nbsp;test </b><i>for </i>extracting&nbsp;</u>stuff`

So I could then assign that string to a variable?

Comment: `var html = $('label').html();`: https://jsfiddle.net/9L27jyvf/

Comment: How is it related to AngularJS?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, well today I learned that's a thing.. I feel dumb for having had to ask at all. Thanks for the help man.

Comment: @DmitryParzhitsky I was not aware if angular provided tools to accomplish this from a controller via js, so I added the tag since I'm using the framework just to be sure.

Comment: No problems. Just for your reference, the jQuery docs are very good, and worth a quick scan. You can get a good idea of what most of the methods do just from their names: http://api.jquery.com

Comment: @KevinB Not really a reason to downvote my question, but thanks for your personal opinion that provided no additional substance to the conversation what-so-ever. Have a good one, bro.

Comment: @Chris That certainly wasn't my reason, but no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you simply want

```
var x = $("label").html();
```

(providing you have one label)
see the [jquery documentation for html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

$("label") returns a jquery-object.
you can read the html with the html-method.
you can also write the html with this method:

```
$("label").html("<b>the new content</b>");
```

You can also simply do it without jquery:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("label")[0].innerHTML;
```

getElementsByTagName returns an elementcollection.
If there's only one label. the first one is the one you want.
innerHTML is the propery that contains the HTML.

You might be better of if you give your label an ID.

```
<label id="myLabel"> 
    ...
</label>
```

then you could do:

```
var x = $("#myLabel").html();
var y = document.getElementByID("myLabel").innerHTML;
```